# insight into disappeared answer

Tags: support, moderation

My question here: [Finding capacitors with low soakage (dielectric absorption)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39586/finding-capacitors-with-low-soakage-dielectric-absorption) had a second answer a short while ago, with some comments.  It (and the comments) are now invisible to me.  Since my rep here is rather lower than on SO, I can't see for myself what the disposition of that answer is.

Would someone be so kind as to tell me what happened to that other answer?  IMO it was valuable.  I'd especially like to know whether it was deleted by the answerer or a diamond mod.

Answer (score 5):

Deleted by diamond mod as a post by a suspended user making sock puppet accounts.